# Python3: Manipulate list over which to iterate whithin the iteration itself

Tags: python, loops

I want to solve the following problem with a python script:

I have a list A of coordinates(defined by the x and y value of the start and endpoint of a 2D-line). I want to pick the first coordinate from A, write it into a new list B and remove it from A. Then I want to Iterate over A and search for a coordinate where the endpoint of the old coordinate is the same as the start point of the new coordinate (basically like Dominoes)(there is either one or zero match). If a matching one is found, it shall be written into B, removed from A and define the new start for another iteration over A. If at some point match is found, I want to just grab the first coordinate from A as a start point. This shall happen until A=[].

The code produces no error, but the output is just wrong and makes no sense.
I believe the while True loop it wrong, but since i manipulate the linecoords list within the loop, I cant use a for i in linecoords here!? I am thankful for any help! Thanks! (:

```
linecoords = A

todraw = B

linecoords = [(xstart1,ystart1,xend1,yend1),(xstart2,ystart2,xend2,yend2),...]

while linecoords != []:
    todraw = []
    while True:
        temp = linecoords[0]
        todraw.append(temp)
        del linecoords[0]

        for j in linecoords:
            if (j[0]==temp[2] and j[1]==temp[3]):
                todraw.append(j)
                temp = j
                linecoords.remove(j)
                break
        break

    print(todraw)
    plotline(todraw) #function to draw this list
   

     continue
```

part of the output:

```py
[[175.0, 100.0, 175.0, 105.0]]
[[175.0, 110.0, 175.0, 115.0]]
[[175.0, 120.0, 175.0, 125.0]]
[[175.0, 130.0, 175.0, 135.0]]
[[175.0, 140.0, 175.0, 145.0]]
[[175.0, 150.0, 175.0, 155.0]]
[[175.0, 160.0, 175.0, 165.0]]
[[175.0, 170.0, 175.0, 175.0]]
[[77.5, 42.0, 77.5, 42.5]]
[[67.75, 29.2, 67.75, 29.25]]
[[66.775, 27.92, 66.775, 27.925]]
[[66.6775, 27.792, 66.6775, 27.7925]]
[[66.66775, 27.7792, 66.66775, 27.77925]]
[[66.666775, 27.77792, 66.666775, 27.777925]]
[[66.6666775, 27.777792, 66.6666775, 27.7777925]]
[[66.66666775, 27.7777792, 66.66666775, 27.777779250000002]]
[[66.666666775, 27.77777792, 66.666666775, 27.777777925]]
[[66.6666666775, 27.777777792, 66.6666666775, 27.7777777925]]
[[66.66666666775001, 27.7777777792, 66.66666666775001, 27.777777779250002]]
[[66.666666666775, 27.77777777792, 66.666666666775, 27.777777777925]]
[[66.6666666666775, 27.777777777792, 66.6666666666775, 27.7777777777925]]
[[66.66666666666775, 27.7777777777792, 66.66666666666775, 27.77777777777925]]
[[66.66666666666677, 27.77777777777792, 66.66666666666677, 27.777777777777924]]
[[180.0, 35.0, 180.0, 40.0]]
[[180.0, 45.0, 180.0, 50.0]]
[[180.0, 55.0, 180.0, 60.0]]
[[180.0, 65.0, 180.0, 70.0]]
[[180.0, 75.0, 180.0, 80.0]]
[[180.0, 85.0, 180.0, 90.0]]
[[180.0, 95.0, 180.0, 100.0]]
[[180.0, 105.0, 180.0, 110.0]]
[[180.0, 115.0, 180.0, 120.0]]
[[180.0, 125.0, 180.0, 130.0]]
[[180.0, 135.0, 180.0, 140.0]]
[[180.0, 145.0, 180.0, 150.0]]
[[180.0, 155.0, 180.0, 160.0]]
[[180.0, 165.0, 180.0, 170.0]]
[[180.0, 175.0, 180.0, 180.0]]
```

Comment: When you stepped through it line-by-line with a debugger did you notice any place where things looked suspicious?  When you inspected/printed values and/or conditions at various points in your program was there an obvious place where it was misbehaving?

Comment: 1) Your `while true` and `break` cancel each other out. 2) It's strange that you are using del in one instance and remove in the other.

Comment: `while linecoords != []` should be just `while linecoords`

Comment: added output, but is while true suitable here? How do I get out of it then?

Comment: `white True` is pointless give that you `break` at the first iteration.